# How can I use a PrimeNg p-table without an array object?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'd like to use a [primeNg p-table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) to show some properties on an object instead of an array while keeping the prime styling.

With this the body does not show up at all while the header does. I'd prefer to not have to put my single object in an array just to satisfy primeng.

```
  <p-table [responsive]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>
          Lot Start Date
        </th>
        <th>
          Expiration Date
        </th>
        <th>
          Quantity
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <tr>
      <td>10/12/19</td>
      <td>12/12/19</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </p-table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can binding object's property to `td` like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydbzpi)

```
<p-table #table [value]="[{}]">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Lot Start Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Expiration Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
        <tr>
            <td>10/12/19</td>
            <td>12/12/19</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

or add object into an array

ts

```
data: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.data = [
      {
        lot_start_date: '10/12/19',
        expiration_date: '12/12/19',
        quantity: 50
      }
    ];
  }
```

html

```
<p-table #table [value]="data">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Lot Start Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Expiration Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ rowData.lot_start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ rowData.expiration_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ rowData.quantity }}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: Is there any way to filter through a table like this? It works as expected, but typical global filters no longer work